# mysql if first value "firstname" is null don't show the rest of the table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i'm trying to make it work

how do i tell mysql to dont show anything in case firstname is null?

```
<?php


  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Form"); 

   echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>firstname</th>
  <th>lastname</th>
  <th>email</th>
  <th>comment</th>
  </tr>";


    ?>
```

Comment: Just use if condition, simple

Comment: Try to post full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use conditions in your `PHP`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Form"); 

if (!empty($result['firstname'])) {
    echo "<table border='1'>
      <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>firstname</th>
      <th>lastname</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>comment</th>
    </tr>";
}
```

**EDIT 1:** In case you have empty value in your cell, `IS NOT NULL` will not work, use the following:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Form WHERE firstname <> ''");
```

or both

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Form WHERE firstname <> '' AND firstname IS NOT NULL");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Form WHERE firstname NOT IS NULL;
```

This should be the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Form WHERE firstname IS NOT NULL AND firstname != '';
```

> MySQL IS NOT NULL operator will check whether a value is not NULL. -